# Clone a table in MySql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, clone

Estoy intentando clonar una tabla mysql con código php, cuando ejecuto el código me indica que se ha creado correctamente:

**"New record created successfully"**

Pero lo reviso en la consola de MySql y no aparece la tabla, entonces lo intento de nuevo y me sale el mensaje:

**"Error: CREATE TABLE product2 LIKE product; Table 'product2' already exists**

```
<?php 
$servername = "xxxxx";
$database = "xxxxx";
$user = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $database);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product2 SELECT * FROM product;";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Parece que todo indica que existe, pero no existe, lo he revisado y no aparece la tabla nueva.

Consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado con SHOW TABLES; ?   (Solo por si acaso, el método que usas para clonar la tabla tan solo clona la estructura, no los datos).

Comment: Sí, lo se, he probado clonar datos y estructura y es igual, genera el mismo mensaje pero no aparece la tabla. También he ejecutado SHOW TABLES y lista las tablas igual  que en la consola de MySql pero no muestra la que dice que ya existe.

Comment: quiero creer que las conexiones son las mismas, no?

Comment: otra cosa, el usuario que usas para las dos cosas es el mismo? no vaya a ser que uno tenga permisos y el otro no...

Comment: La conexión es correcta, la he camuflado con "xxxx", localhost, user, password y nombre de base de datos es correcta, La clonación es dentro de la misma base de datos, no es una clonación de dos tablas desde diferentes bases de datos.

Comment: ¿Qué significa *Pero lo reviso en la consola de MySql*? ¿Exactamente qué es la consola de MySQL? ¿Cómo compruebas si ha creado o no la tabla nueva?

Comment: He añadido pantallazo de la "consola". Yo le llamo así, me refiero al entorno php MyAdmin.

Comment: En el panel de la izquierda están tus bases de datos, revisa en la BD a la que te estás conectando cuando ejecutas el `CREATE TABLE`, me parece que el problema es que no estás mirando en la BD correcta.

Comment: Por otra parte, no sé si hay paginación en tu interfaz de PHPMyAdmin ¿? Tu nueva tabla empezaría por `p` y ahí nos muestras tablas hasta la letra `k` ¿revisaste si no hay algo que diga `"Mostrar 50"` o parecido, pudiendo editar el número  `50` o el que sea  para poder mostrar más tablas en una sola página, o si hay flechas del tipo `>>`  para ir al siguiente grupo? O, ¿probaste a escribir `producto` en la parte del filtro?

Comment: Sí, es la base de datos correcta,  sobre la paginación, sí, hay 2 páignas, cuando hice el pantallazo estaba en la 2, pero igual, en la página uno ya la había revisado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en mi opinión primero deberías crear la tabla donde se desea clonar datos:

```
CREATE TABLE productos_backup LIKE productos;
```

Seguido procedes a clonar datos:

```
INSERT INTO productos_backup SELECT * FROM productos;
```

Con tu código quedaría algo así:

```
<?php 
//datos server
$servername = localhost
$database = "test";
$user = "root";
$password = "12345678";

// Crea conexion
$mysqli  = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $database);

//comprobar la conexión
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

//creando la tabla product2
if (!$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product2 LIKE product")) {
    echo "Falló la creación de la tabla: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//clonando datos a tabla product2
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT product2 SELECT * FROM product")) {
    echo "Falló en clonacion de datos: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//cerrar conexion
$mysqli -> close();
?>
```

Espero sea de utilidad y a la orden!

Comment: Genial, Diego, ha funcionado, es curioso que haciéndolo todo en la misma instrucción no me permitiera procesar el algoritmo. Muchas gracias.